# How save php script as bytecode

Tags: php, bytecode

I have **some_script.php.** How I can convert this file in **bytecode** form?
Which is a state after the initial processing of the script by the php-analyzer.
Something like **.pyc** form for **.py**-scripts in **python**.

Is it possible to do this with the help of an actual version php-interpreter(7.1)?
Since tools like **bcompiler** look undeveloped today:(.

Comment: *Why* do you want this? Perhaps you're really looking for a PHP opcode cache…?!

Comment: @deceze That would make the script difficult to edit in a production environment.

Comment: So you want it as a form of obfuscation…?

Comment: @deceze Yes. In general terms, yes.

Comment: There's one solution that is used by facebook, called HipHop for PHP. Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132016/how-to-install-hiphop-for-php